# Oscillation and Hölder continuity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Where can I find a proof of the following fact?

> If
> $$w(u,x_{0},r)=\sup _{B_{r}(x_{0})}u-\inf _{B_{r}(x_{0})}u$$
> for some function $u(x)$ satisfies
> $$ w\left(u,x_{0},{\tfrac {r}{2}}\right)\leq \lambda w\left(u,x_{0},r\right)$$
> for a fixed $0 < \lambda < 1$ and all sufficiently small values of $r$, then $u$ is Hölder continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just prove it yourself:

Take $r=1$. Then
$$w(x_0,2^{-n})\leq \lambda^n w(x_0,1)=:C\lambda^n.$$
To estimate $|u(x_0)-u(y)|$, where $y$ is close to $x_0$, choose $n$ so that
$|x_0-y|\in[2^{-n-1},2^{-n}].$
Then
$$|u(x_0)-u(y)|\leq w(x_0,2^{-n})\leq C\lambda^{n}=C. 2^{-hn}\leq 2^hC_1|x_0-y|^h,$$
where $h=-\log\lambda/\log2$.